# Golang templates won't load

Tags: go, go-templates, go-gin

I started to write a Gin application and my project tree looks like

```
-assets
--css
---{bootstrap}
-templates
--layouts
---footer.html
---head.html
---header.html
--book.html
-main.go
```

In main.go I load templates and there is no error

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/layouts/*.html")
```

I define templates

```
{{ define "head" }}
<head>
    //Head
</head>
 {{ end }}
```

And I nest them

```
 {{ define "header" }}
 {{ template "head.html" . }}
 //HTML
 {{ end }}
```

But when I try to use them, I get empty output

```
 {{ template "header" . }}
 <h1>{{ .Title}}</h1>

 <h3>{{ .Author.Fullname}}</h3>
```

[Edit] Function that executes the template:

```
func getBook(c *gin.Context) {
//DB stuff
var book models.Book
t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/book.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
t.Execute(c.Writer, book)
}
```

Full-code can be found on [github](https://github.com/alzaburetz/Bookstore)

Comment: What does "I get nothing" mean? No error? Empty output? Please do include how you try to execute the templates. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: You're not checking the error returned by `t.Execute()`. Please do so.

Answer (score 3):

`router.LoadHTMLGlob` and `template.ParseFiles` are two separate approaches to deal with templates. The template returned by `ParseFiles` has no knowledge of the templates loaded by `LoadHTMLGlob`. Once you decide to use `LoadHTMLGlob` you should then use [`c.HTML`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.HTML) to render your templates. And the `name` argument to this [`c.HTML`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.HTML) method would be either the name specified in a `{{define "name"}}` *action* or the *base name* of the template file (including the extention I believe).

So in your case you should probably do something like this:

```
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "book.html", book)
```

More examples can be found here: https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/html-rendering/

Keep in mind that [`LoadHTMLGlob`](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/gin.go#L192-L200) relies on [`template.ParseGlob`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob) which states:

> When parsing multiple files with the same name in different
>   directories, the last one mentioned will be the one that results.

That means that if you want all of your templates to be accessible through `c.HTML` you need to make sure that they either have unique *base names* or they need to contain the `{{ define "name"}}` action.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from the default templating system where 'everything simply worked' to Gin is a bit confusing, namely, there seem to be some naming restrictions when using files for templates. I have no idea if this is the case, but, in *my* setup, I had to make sure that:

- The name of the template (the `define` keyword) needs to be the *filename* — at least when that's the only `define` in the template (I haven't tested with multiple `defines`) — i.e. if you're using `./templates/book.html` as a template, you need to have `{{ define "book.html" }}` at the top of that file (this is true for templates included in other templates; I didn't experiment with `blocks` or other more esoteric ways to jinx templates together)
- Similarly, when calling `c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "book.html", book)`, you have to put the *full name* of the file containing that template (as shown!)

In other words, although the manual says otherwise, and @mkopriva confirms what the manual says, I have had a different experience: it was only I started matching the filename with the `define` and the `c.HTML()` call that I stopped getting blank pages...

Also, while running from the console (in debug mode), it was clear that my programme was 'finding' far more templates than it should — namely, almost every template was duplicated (one copy for the filename, another copy for the `define`, etc.). This confused not only me but the application itself...